# Bundle pdflatex to run on an AWS Lambda with a custom AMI image

Tags: python, lambda, pdflatex

My goal is to create an Amazon Lambda Function to compile .tex files into .pdf using the pdflatex tool through python.

I've built an EC2 instance using Amazon's AMI and installed pdflatex using yum:

`yum install texlive-collection-latex.noarch`

This way, I can use the pdflatex and my python code works, compiling my .tex into a .pdf the way I want.

Now, I need to create a .zip file bundle containing the pdflatex tool; latexcodec (a python library I've used, no problem with this one); and my python files: handler (lambda function handler) and worker (which compiles my .tex file).

This bundle is the deployment package needed to upload my code and libraries to Amazon Lambda.

The problem is: pdflatex has a lot of dependencies, and I'd have to gather everything in one place. I've found a script which does that for me:

http://www.metashock.de/2012/11/export-binary-with-lib-dependencies/

I've set my PATH to find the pdflatex binary at the new directory so I can use it and I had an issue: pdflatex couldn't find some dependencies. I was able to fix it by setting an environment variable to the folder where the script moved everything to:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/ec2-user/lambda/local/lib64:/home/ec2-user/lambda/local/usr/lib64"
```

At this point, I was running pdflatex directly, through bash. But my python script was firing an error when trying to use the pdflatex:

```
mktexfmt: No such file or directory
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
```

I was also able to solve this by moving the `pdflatex.fmt` and `texmf.cnf` files to my bundle folder and setting some environment variables as well:

```
export TEXFORMATS=/home/ec2-user/lambda/local/usr/bin
```

And now, my current problem, the python script keeps throwing the following error:

```
---! /home/ec2-user/lambda/local/usr/bin/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

I've found some possible solutions; deleting a `.texmf-var` folder, which in my case, does not exist; using `fmtutil`, which I don't have in my AMI image...

1 - Was I missing any environment variable?

2 - Or moving my pdflatex binary and all its dependencies the wrong way?

3 - Is there any correct way to move a binary and all its dependencies so it can be used in other machine (considering the env variables)?

Answer (score 1):

Lambda environment is a container and not a common EC2 Instance. All files in your .zip is deployed in `/var/task/` inside the container. By the way, everything is mounted as read-only, except the directory `/tmp`. So, it's impossible to run a `yum`, for example.

For you case, I'd recommend you to put the binaries in your zip and invoke it in `/var/task/<binary name>`. Remember to put a  binary compiled statically in a linux compatible with the container's kernel.

Comment: I know, I'm using this instance, because it's the same infrastructure that a lambda function uses. So it would not have any compatibility problems. But before putting everything inside a zip file I have to make sure that my python handler can use everything from one place (int this case, my /home/ec2-user/lambda/local), then I'll change it to `var/task/<binary name>` to zip it all.
For sure, everything is read-only, I'm using yum to set up pdflatex so I can bundle it in my deployment package

Answer (score 0):

samoconnor is doing pretty much exactly what you want in https://github.com/samoconnor/lambdalatex. Note that he sets environment variables in his handler [function](https://github.com/samoconnor/lambdalatex/blob/master/lambda_function.py)

```
os.environ['PATH'] += ":/var/task/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux/"
os.environ['HOME'] = "/tmp/latex/"
os.environ['PERL5LIB'] = "/var/task/texlive/2017/tlpkg/TeXLive/"
```

that might do the trick for you as-well.